# how to introduce a new version / different logic for ActionFilter in c#

Tags: c#, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

I am trying to change the way our existing c# application handles security.  The end result is that a we will use a new "user" object that looks different from the current user object we have.  But we want to introduce this user model in a way that won't break existing code.  Until we finish migrating all our old code, we will have 2 ways of handling security / determining what functionality a user is allowed to access.

**How the Code Works Today**

As a part of our authentication process, when a user logs in, we load a their profile from our database, and this profile includes a list of application permissions.

Here's a sample controller that would trigger the security logic:

```
    [Route("me/permissions")]
    [HttpGet]
    [SecuredEndpoint(WidgetAppPermissions.General)]
    public string DoSomethingAmazing(GetAmazingDataRequest request)
    {
        try
        {               
            var x = someAmazingObject.DoSomething()
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

This is what the GetAmazingDataRequest class looks like:

```
    public class GetAmazingDataRequest : Request
    {
       
    }
```

And the logic behind the SecuredEndpoint attribute looks like this: (note: it's a public sealed class)

```
 public sealed class SecuredEndpointAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly WidgetAppPermissions[] functions;

    public SecuredEndpointAttribute(params WidgetAppPermissions[] functions)
    {
        this.functions = functions;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {

        //it's inside this method that eventually we call GetUserProfile to load the user
          profile from the database, including the list of permissions.

        var user = userRepo.GetUserProfile(context.HttpContext.User);
```

The idea is that the OnActionExecuting() logic checks the user's profile that was retrieved from the database to ensure that he / she has, in this case, a permission called "General" included in their profile.  If they do, then the execution returns and the system actually tries the logic inside the DoSomethingAmazing() method.

**What I Tried**

The system runs the SecuredEndPoint attribute logic before actually running the logic inside the DoSomethingAmazing().  But while debugging I noticed that the name of the request class is included inside the "context" object that's passed into OnActionExecuting()

So I was thinking that for each method in any controller that we want to 'migrate', we could change the request object to include a new property like

```
    public class Request
    {
       public virtual bool securityVersionBeta {get; set;} = false; 
    }

    public class GetAmazingDataRequest : Request
    {
       public virtual bool securityVersionBeta {get; set;} = true;
    }
```

And then I can hijack the existing OnActionExecuting to include a new check:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (((GetAmazingDataRequest )context.ActionArguments["Request"]).securityVersionBeta)
        {
            newProfileLogic(context);
        } else
        {
            Originalcode(context);
        }
```

**Questions**

Do you see anything glaring bad / wrong about this approach?  Is there another approach that would allow us to migrate our code in a piecemeal fashion?
Any other suggestions would also be appreciated.

Comment: first of all, I would never load entire user profile on each http request, and if I have to do it, it is part of the business logic not the controllers, still back to your question, my two cents on, I would inject userRepo.GetUserProfile User (IPrincipal) other claims  (not just token validated claims, jwt/saml), claims that would determine what is allowed to do here, I mean using a middleware or even better at token validation, and from context user any policy or custom attribute should do the trick

Comment: Missed the last part, seeing it now, most definitely everything goes in business logic, any approach to decide what endpoint does outside of endpoint is a hazard that can cause major issues. To sum up, any authorization related claims done at authorization middleware and any variation on endpoint response based on profile done on business logic. It is old school, but is safe and maintainable on my opinion.

Comment: check this great article, it is a bit old, in dotnet 6 and 7 other tricks can be done, but either way, https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/a-better-way-to-handle-authorization-in-asp-net-core/ as an idea of injecting extra claims based on something defined in DB

Comment: @SilentTremor I'll take  a look at the article.  Looks interesting.  But just to make sure I understand your comments, you're saying ... the logic that checks to see if User X should be allowed to call endpoint ABC should happen inside endpoint ABC and not in the OnActionExecuting() method?

Comment: yes, exactly, everything that if x do y should be part of the flow/business logic

Comment: only thing that I would add at middleware/token validation layer, db stored claims to be injected there in context user (IPrincipal)

Comment: and based on determined claims you can write the attributes or security polices that allow users who got specific claims (like "WidgetAppPermissions": "General" ) if this is neeed